# Stop users from printing if cells are not filled

Tags: excel, vba, validation, printing

I need to create a macro to **prevent users from printing** if certain cells are not filled.

I found this code online and slightly adjusted it to suit my preference but I'm not sure where to input the `activesheet_print` code to start then stop the print if any of the ranges are empty. Please help me out guys!

```
Sub QuickPrint()

Dim Start As Boolean
Dim rng As Range
Dim Prompt As String
Dim RngStr As String
Dim Cell As Range
'set your ranges here to suit your needs.

Set ws = Sheets("Form")
With ws
Set rng = Union(.Range("E2:E5"), .Range("E9"), .Range("V9"), .Range("E10:E11"), .Range("M10:M11"), .Range("V10:V11"), .Range("H15"), .Range("H17"), .Range("H19"), .Range("H21"), .Range("H23"), .Range("M35"))
End With
'prompt message if there are blank cells
Prompt = "Please ensure all cells are filled."
Start = True


For Each Cell In rng
If Cell.Value = vbNullString Then
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow
Cancel = True
If Start Then RngStr = RngStr & "X" & vbCrLf
Start = False
RngStr = RngStr
Else
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'no color
End If
Next

If RngStr <> "" Then
RngStr = Left$(RngStr, Len(RngStr) - 1)
Cancel= True
Else
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End if

If RngStr <> "" Then
MsgBox Prompt, vbCritical, "Incomplete Data"
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone who helped out. The code is working right now. Feel free to use it if ever needed. Cheers!

Comment: Hint: a range can contain more than one cell (like `Range("E2:E5")`)...  Also, you can declare more than one variable on a line (like `Dim rng as range, rng2 as range` etc)

Comment: After fixing the code spacing/indentation it's clear that you have a number of issues to address, starting with a couple dozen missing `End If`'s.  This is an insane amount of unnecessary repetition. It's time that you learn about VBA Loops among other things. Here's a basic tutorial to get your started: [**Excel VBA For Beginners**](//www.homeandlearn.org/)  See also, the [tour] and "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve], as well as what's on-topic at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hey ashleedawg, thanks for replying. Fyi I'm trying to ensure an application form is filled. Regarding the "End If's", I know that I'm missing two end if's for each "rng" blocks. but everytime I try to put it in, the compile error would appear. The current code works for any existing empty cells. it's just that I can't get it to NOT print if there are any empty cells.

Comment: hey @ashleedawg, I just checked on past questions. Apparently, if "IF & ELSE" statement ends in one line, then no extra "END IF's" are needed. That is why the "lack of" end if doesn't affect my coding. Could you give me some advice regarding the print issue , as my current code is working fine. (stops me from exiting the file if any cells are empty, but doesn't stop me from printing)

Comment: Take a look at the [BeforePrint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeprint) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few things I've noted while looking through your code.

```vb
Dim rng, rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8, rng9, rng10, rng11, rng12 As Range
```

Out of all of these ranges, only rng12 is an actual range, the rest of them are `Variant/Object/Range`.

I would suggest specifying each variable as a range, or creating a single range -

```
Dim myRange As Range, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Form")
With ws
    Set myRange = Union(.Range("E2:E5"), .Range("E9"), .Range("V9"), .Range("E10:E11"), .Range("M10:M11"), .Range("V10:V11"), .Range("H15"), .Range("H17"), .Range("H19"),.Range("H21"), .Range("H23"), .Range("M35"))
End With
```

I made some minor changes to the structure of your final if block for determining if the print should fail, tested & it works fine. Full complete code below -

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myRange As Range, ws As Worksheet, start As Boolean, prompt As String, rngStr As String, cell As Range

    ' build up your range
    Set ws = Sheets("Form")
    With ws
        Set myRange = Union(.Range("E2:E5"), .Range("E9"), .Range("V9"), .Range("E10:E11"), .Range("M10:M11"), .Range("V10:V11"), .Range("H15"), .Range("H17"), .Range("H19"), .Range("H21"), .Range("H23"), .Range("M35"))
    End With

    'prompt message if there are blank cells
    prompt = "Please ensure all cells are filled."
    start = True


    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = vbNullString Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'color yellow
        If start And cell.Value = vbNullString Then
            rngStr = rngStr & "X" & vbCrLf
            start = False
            rngStr = rngStr
        Else
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 '** no color
        End If
    Next cell

    If rngStr <> "" Then
        rngStr = Left$(rngStr, Len(rngStr) - 1)
        If rngStr <> "" Then
            MsgBox prompt, vbCritical, "Incomplete Data"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You want to place this code inside the `ThisWorkbook` section of your VBAProject.

If you want to check if the worksheet is protected first, there are two approaches you could take.

You could edit your the range build up as follows -

```
' build up your range
Set ws = Sheets("Form")
If ws.ProtectContents Then Exit Sub
With ws
    Set myRange = Union(.Range("E2:E5"), .Range("E9"), .Range("V9"), .Range("E10:E11"), .Range("M10:M11"), .Range("V10:V11"), .Range("H15"), .Range("H17"), .Range("H19"), .Range("H21"), .Range("H23"), .Range("M35"))
End With
```

Or you could create an extra function in a separate module (allows for multiple use) & use as follows -

```
' Separate module 'Module1'
Option Explicit

Public Function IsSheetLocked(sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
    If sheet.ProtectContents Then IsSheetLocked = True
End Function
```

And update your main sub to -

```
' build up your range
Set ws = Sheets("Form")
If IsSheetLocked(ws) Then Exit Sub
With ws
    Set myRange = Union(.Range("E2:E5"), .Range("E9"), .Range("V9"), .Range("E10:E11"), .Range("M10:M11"), .Range("V10:V11"), .Range("H15"), .Range("H17"), .Range("H19"), .Range("H21"), .Range("H23"), .Range("M35"))
End With
```

Edit1: Fixed logic to fix issue with failing once values are filled in correctly.

Edit2: Added an extra step to check if the worksheet is locked